# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController::destroy(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

i can not delete it by id

and i have some code here for Model too

```
class Category extends Model
{

    // Table Name
    protected $table = 'categories';
    // Primary Key

    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    // TimeStamps
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $fillable= ['name','icon'];


    public function getAllCategory(){
        return DB::table(categories)->get();

    }

    public function createCategory($name,$icon){
            $category= $this->create([
                'name' => $name,
                'icon' => $icon,
            ]);
            return $category;
    }
}
```

//here is a function in controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $category = Category::findOrFail($id);
    $category->delele();
    return redirect('/admin.category');

}
```

Comment: `delelet()` or `delete()`? post also your route, please

Comment: Yup, in the ```destroy``` method of the controller you typed ```delele``` instead of ```delete```

Comment: How did you called destroy method? Can you share your routes/web.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your routes/web.php file
You have to pass one argument to destroy method
eg:

```
Route::get('delete_category/{id}', 'CategoryController@destroy');
```

And your invoking URL will look like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete_category/1`
Here 1 will take as the value of `id` variable

Answer (score 0):

The problem is rather somewhere in your view. You have route for example `category.destroy` but you need to pass `id` of model you want to destroy when creating link and you miss it and that's why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

You have one typo mistake and need some changes

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $category = Category::findOrFail($id);
    $category->delete(); //type mistake
    return redirect('/admin.category');  // it seems like route name

}
```

Better code

```
public function destroy($id)
{
     $category = Category::findOrFail($id);
      if($category) {
       $category->delete();
       return redirect()->route('admin.category' ,['error' => $error]);
      }  

    return redirect()->route('admin.category');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot the name of the "Request" class.

Correct Parameter definition.

```
public function displayId(Request $Visitor){
return $Visitor->id;
}
```

Wrong Parameter definition.

```
public function displayId($Visitor){
return $Visitor->id;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

SOLUTION : php artisan route:cache work on terminal.
I use that line and it worked. Firstly you check php artisan route:list and if you do not see destroy/{id} in list, you should work that command. To make that clear your route does not see {id} but when you work command, route paths in web.php update itself

Comment: Can you please post the entire code snippet with your line, so it possible to see where the line should be?

Comment: @Olov I explained that. If it does not work, ı share my code